# Nuxtjs dynamic routes not accepting payload when "full static"

Tags: javascript, deployment, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

When I run `nuxt generate` with `target: "static"` in my `nuxt.config.js`, my dynamically-created routes do not accept their payload, which they get like so:

```
****nuxt.config.js****
generate: {
    routes() {
      return axios
        .get(`${process.env.ROOT_URL}/businesses`)
        .then(res => {
          return res.data.map(business => {
            return {
              route: `/business/${business.id}`,
              payload: business
            };
          });
        });
     }
}

****business.vue****
async asyncData({ params, store, error, payload }) {
    if (payload) {
      console.log('GOT PAYLOAD!', payload);
      return { business: payload };
    } else {
      // other stuff
    }
})
```

During `nuxt generate` the console.log above is hit for each dynamic route, so I know it's receiving its correct payload.

After `nuxt generate` my `dist` folder has a subfolder for each dynamic route, but the `index.html` for each has only a few lines inside , and when I visit the page for each on the browser no content specific to the dynamic route appears (the navbar from my `layout` component comes up fine).

Navigation in app works fine, so if I go to a different page and come page to my dynamic route content will appear, so `asyncData` works, accepting the payload is the trouble.

Without `target: "static"` things work as expected, the `index.html` for each in `dist` has plenty in it, and the page loads the desired content when visited, although the `head()` method in business.vue is not generated (see my question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147401/in-nuxtjs-will-dynamic-route-head-tags-populate-for-seo)).

Can anyone point out what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: does this PR address the issue you described? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/8314

Comment: Have you found a solution? Because I'm having the same problem as you.